# Why does this happen in HTML while creating tables?

Tags: html, css, xml, xhtml

I've written a XML code to create tables. But, the problem is whenever I remove the nested  tag from a specific block the table row alternates.
SOURCE CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "~//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1/EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1.dtd">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="border-collapse=collapse" border="2">
<tr><td rowspan="20"><b>Department</b></td></tr>
<tr><tr><td rowspan="5">Sem1</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub1</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub2</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub3</td></tr></tr>
<tr><tr><td rowspan="5">Sem2</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub4</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub5</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub6</td></tr></tr>
<tr><tr><td rowspan="5">Sem3</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub7</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub8</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub9</td></tr></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Any solutions?

OUTPUT
[correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmO28.png)

But when i remove the  i.e. the one outside, which encloses 4 lines of code.

```
<--!tr tag removed--> <tr><td rowspan="5">Sem2</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub4</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub5</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub6</td></tr> <--!tr tag removed-->
```

the output comes like this
[wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdVyb.png)

Comment: As far as I know, `tr` can only have `td` as children.

Comment: If you're not going to serve your XHTML with `application/xhtml+xml` mime-type - and you're clearly not - stop trying to use XHTML. What you have is broken HTML.

Comment: `<tr><tr>` is nonsense.  The image depicts a particular layout which you achieve with a combination of colspan and rowspan - not nested `tr` tags

Answer (score 0):

Leaving out the issue of XHTML already addressed in comments, you probably want HTML code such as the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td rowspan="20"><b>Department</b></td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan="3">Sem1</td><td>sub1</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub2</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub3</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan="3">Sem2</td><td>sub4</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub5</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub6</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan="3">Sem3</td><td>sub7</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub8</td></tr>
<tr><td>sub9</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The effect you're observing with `rowspan=5` is that when an HTML parser encounters a `<tr>` tag immediately followed by another `<tr>` tag, a `</tr>` end-element tag is inferred before the second `<tr>` start-element tag, and thus an empty table row in counted towards the rowspan value.

To get an idea of how this behavior of HTML parsers (originally derived from SGML end-tag inference) works, consider the above corrected HTML code with `</tr>` elements omitted:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td rowspan="20"><b>Department</b></td>
<tr><td rowspan="3">Sem1</td><td>sub1</td>
<tr><td>sub2</td>
<tr><td>sub3</td>
<tr><td rowspan="3">Sem2</td><td>sub4</td>
<tr><td>sub5</td>
<tr><td>sub6</td>
<tr><td rowspan="3">Sem3</td><td>sub7</td>
<tr><td>sub8</td>
<tr><td>sub9</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The latter is equivalent to the former according to the HTML specification which states that

> A tr element's end tag can be omitted if the tr element is immediately followed by another tr element, or if there is no more content in the parent element.

And in fact, an SGML parser can infer those (provided `<DOCTYPE html>` is changed to `<!DOCTYPE html "about:legacy">` to tell SGML the HTML parsing rules as explained in eg. https://sgmljs.net/docs/parsing-html-tutorial/parsing-html-tutorial.html; actually, even `</td>` end-elements can be omitted; this however isn't implemented in the built-in `about:legacy-compat` HTML mini-DTD of `sgmlproc` though, so one needs to use the full HTML DTD).

<s>Now I would've loved to send you to [W3C's nu HTML 5 validator](https://validator.w3.org) to check your HTML but its results are confusing (check it our yourself), seemingly inferring additional `tbody` start-element tags, which isn't backed by the content model specification for the `table` element:</s>

> In this order: optionally a caption element, followed by zero or more colgroup elements, followed optionally by a thead element, followed by either zero or more tbody elements or one or more tr elements, followed optionally by a tfoot element, optionally intermixed with one or more script-supporting elements.

meaning `tbody` is *optional* and **not** inferred as a wrapper around `tr` elements even though its start- and end-elements can be omitted. The latter is how the parsing rules are implemented in the HTML5x and the newer 2020 and 2023 HTML Review Draft DTDs at https://sgmljs.net/docs/html5.html. This ambiguity is also briefly discussed in the [the HTML 5 DTD reference](https://sgmljs.net/docs/html5.html#start--and-end-element-tag-omission-in-table-content).

See Alohci's comment regarding nu validator's inference of `tbody` elements.

See also [WHATWG's HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html) for the referenced citations.

Comment: The table's content model allows `tr` elements to be valid children of the table element specifically for the benefit of HTML5's XML syntax (a.k.a. XHTML). While the HTML parser will always infer a missing `tbody`, the XML parser will not, and since, for largely historic reasons, browsers fully support `table` elements which directly contain their `tr`s, there's no good reason to exclude it from the table's content model.

Comment: @Alohci Could you elaborate/provide further links? WHATWG's HTML spec doesn't mention anything special wrt XHTML and TBODY. The wording of TBODY's *contexts in which this element can be used* rules is "as a child of a table element, after any caption, colgroup, and thead elements, but only if there are no tr elements that are children of the table element" hence don't support your reading either though *insofar* consistent with HTML 4, but still against what the WHATWG spec says. Thx for an interesting discussion!

Comment: "WHATWG's HTML spec doesn't mention anything special wrt XHTML and TBODY". It doesn't, because it doesn't have to. Section 13 of the spec is about the HTML syntax & parser, section 14 is about the XML syntax & parser, and except where specifically stated, all the other sections are syntax agnostic. In particular, that includes section 4 where the content model and contexts are defined. So the content model is saying that tr elements as direct children of tables is OK, even though the HTML syntax parser can never build such a structure.